# Compare two arbitrary JToken-s of the same structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to compare two arbitrary JTokens of the same type and structure (Json.Net from NewtonSoft).

```
static int CompareTokens(JToken x, JToken y);  
// possible output: 0 / 1 / -1
```

**The main goal** is to be able use this method to sort two Json strings, so that even if in the beginning they had the same data, but in the different order, in the end these are two exactly same strings. So the sort criterion doesn't really matter, it just matters that this criterion is always the same. And each small element of data should be taken into account.

JToken can be of one of next several types: `Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Guid, Integer, Null, Object, Property, String, TimeSpan, Uri`. I don't take into account comparing `Bytes, Comment, Constructor, None, Undefined, Raw`.

- It would be great to gain some idea about comparing *JArrays* and *JObjects*. That should be some recursive comparison, because *JArrays* may consist of other *JArrays* and *JObjects* and vice versa. Any idea would be appreciated.
- But knowing about comparing simpler types would also be very helpful. I wonder rather about knowing how to convert from *JToken* to actual type (than about knowing how to do it logically).
- *JValue* has *IComparable* implemented, but I didn't figure out how to convert simple typed *JToken* to *JValue*. Knowing about this would also be helpful.

Comment: Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` and parse directly into a predefined class because you already know the data incoming. This way you can use standard comparison with all the familiar types of data.

Comment: 1) Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) for [`JToken.DeepEquals`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepEquals.htm), it may give you some ideas.  2) How do you want to compare convertible values such as `1` and `"1"`?

Comment: @dbc That's why he should parse into an Object... There he can specify the type and deal with it accordingly...

Comment: 2) [`JValue`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs) [implements `IComparable<JValue>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_CompareTo.htm), so that's a start.

Comment: @dbc Still a pretty rough one... IComparable defines exactely one function that compares it a bit. Normally this is just used for sorting algorithms. But of course you can do it that way if you really don't want to know the exact inners of the data and just know it's equal. Then he should just try DeepEquals and go with it.

Comment: @SkryptX, Thanks! The problem is that a Poco class in the json may not implement IComparable. GetHashCode() may give different results for the same data. And the type of this class may not be known compile-time. But thanks for help. If json idea doesn't work then i'll have to do something like this, don't know how.

Comment: Who uses an arbitrary getHashCode anyways... I would never use getHashCode except I programmed it myself or it's clearly stated that it is something useful behind.

Comment: @dbc, thanks a lot. I'll think it this direction. However, i didn't fugure out how to get a JValue out of JToken... I'll try to find it out.

Comment: @SkryptX, does DeepEquals take into account the order of the elements in an array? As far as i get it - no. As far as i get it, if the same data is in different order, then DeepEquals will say: "False"...

Comment: Aaaaa, I think i got it. Thanks, guys! :))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Linq-to-JSON, [`JValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) represents a primitive value (string, number, boolean, and so on).  It implements [`IComparable<JValue>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_CompareTo.htm), so Json.NET takes care of sorting primitive values for you.

Building off of that, you're going to need to recursively descend the two `JToken` object hierarchies in parallel.  When you encounter the first token with a different .Net type, or different properties (if not a `JValue`), or with a different value (if a `JValue`), you need to return back the comparison value.

Keep in mind the following:

- A comparison method should be reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.
- Container tokens of different .Net type need to be ordered by type in some consistent manner.
- the child tokens of `JArray` and `JConstructor` are ordered.
- the child tokens of `JObject` are not, so they need to be compared in some stable, symmetric manner.  Walking both in order of *property name* would seem to work.
- There is no obvious way to compare `JRaw`, so don't try, and let an exception get thrown.

The following is a prototype implementation:

```
public class JTokenComparer : IComparer<JToken>
{
    public static JTokenComparer Instance { get { return instance; } }

    static JTokenComparer instance;

    static JTokenComparer()
    {
        instance = new JTokenComparer();
    }

    readonly Dictionary<Type, KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>> dict;

    JTokenComparer()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<Type, KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>>
        {
            // Order chosen semi-arbitrarily.  Putting values first seems reasonable though.
            {typeof(JValue), new KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>(0, new JValueComparer()) },
            {typeof(JProperty), new KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>(1, new JPropertyComparer()) },
            {typeof(JArray), new KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>(2, new JArrayComparer()) },
            {typeof(JObject), new KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>(3, new JObjectComparer()) },
            {typeof(JConstructor), new KeyValuePair<int, IComparer<JToken>>(4, new JConstructorComparer()) },
        };
    }

    #region IComparer<JToken> Members

    public int Compare(JToken x, JToken y)
    {
        if (x is JRaw || y is JRaw)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Tokens of type JRaw cannot be sorted");
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;
        else if (x == null)
            return -1;
        else if (y == null)
            return 1;

        var typeData1 = dict[x.GetType()];
        var typeData2 = dict[y.GetType()];

        int comp;
        if ((comp = typeData1.Key.CompareTo(typeData2.Key)) != 0)
            return comp;
        if (typeData1.Value != typeData2.Value)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("inconsistent dictionary values"); // Internal error
        return typeData2.Value.Compare(x, y);
    }

    #endregion
}

abstract class JTokenComparerBase<TJToken> : IComparer<JToken> where TJToken : JToken
{
    protected TJToken CheckType(JToken item)
    {
        if (item != null && item.GetType() != typeof(TJToken))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Actual type {0} of token \"{1}\" does not match expected type {2}", item.GetType(), item, typeof(TJToken)));
        return (TJToken)item;
    }

    protected bool TryBaseCompare(TJToken x, TJToken y, out int comparison)
    {
        CheckType(x);
        CheckType(y);
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            comparison = 0;
            return true;
        }
        else if (x == null)
        {
            comparison = -1;
            return true;
        }
        else if (y == null)
        {
            comparison = 1;
            return true;
        }
        comparison = 0;
        return false;
    }

    protected abstract int CompareDerived(TJToken x, TJToken y);

    protected int TokenCompare(JToken x, JToken y)
    {
        var tx = CheckType(x);
        var ty = CheckType(y);
        int comp;
        if (TryBaseCompare(tx, ty, out comp))
            return comp;
        return CompareDerived(tx, ty);
    }

    #region IComparer<JToken> Members

    int IComparer<JToken>.Compare(JToken x, JToken y)
    {
        return TokenCompare(x, y);
    }

    #endregion
}

abstract class JContainerOrderedComparerBase<TJToken> : JTokenComparerBase<TJToken> where TJToken : JContainer
{
    protected int CompareItemsInOrder(TJToken x, TJToken y)
    {
        int comp;
        // Dictionary order: sort on items before number of items.
        for (int i = 0, n = Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count); i < n; i++)
            if ((comp = JTokenComparer.Instance.Compare(x[i], y[i])) != 0)
                return comp;
        if ((comp = x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count)) != 0)
            return comp;
        return 0;
    }
}

class JPropertyComparer : JTokenComparerBase<JProperty>
{
    protected override int CompareDerived(JProperty x, JProperty y)
    {
        int comp;
        if ((comp = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)) != 0)
            return comp;
        return JTokenComparer.Instance.Compare(x.Value, y.Value);
    }
}

class JObjectComparer : JTokenComparerBase<JObject>
{
    protected override int CompareDerived(JObject x, JObject y)
    {
        int comp;
        // Dictionary order: sort on items before number of items.
        // Order both property sequences to preserve reflexivity.
        foreach (var propertyComp in x.Properties().OrderBy(p => p.Name).Zip(y.Properties().OrderBy(p => p.Name), (xp, yp) => JTokenComparer.Instance.Compare(xp, yp)))
            if (propertyComp != 0)
                return propertyComp;
        if ((comp = x.Count.CompareTo(y.Count)) != 0)
            return comp;
        return 0;
    }
}

class JArrayComparer : JContainerOrderedComparerBase<JArray>
{
    protected override int CompareDerived(JArray x, JArray y)
    {
        int comp;
        if ((comp = CompareItemsInOrder(x, y)) != 0)
            return comp;
        return 0;
    }
}

class JConstructorComparer : JContainerOrderedComparerBase<JConstructor>
{
    protected override int CompareDerived(JConstructor x, JConstructor y)
    {
        int comp;
        if ((comp = x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)) != 0)
            return comp;
        if ((comp = CompareItemsInOrder(x, y)) != 0)
            return comp;
        return 0;
    }
}

class JValueComparer : JTokenComparerBase<JValue>
{
    protected override int CompareDerived(JValue x, JValue y)
    {
        return Comparer<JToken>.Default.Compare(x, y); // JValue implements IComparable<JValue>
    }
}
```

Lightly tested [prototype fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVkoa4).

Comment: WOW! That's some really great work! Thanks A LOT! What I've been doing by now is not as well-designed. I hope i don't forget to put the 100 points in two days, and hope you get them. But points do not really matter, i'm lucky, because you've saved me the day!

Comment: I'm new to SO and it happens that the possibility of putting +100 is gone after i accepted the answer...

Comment: At the moment the comparison doesn't work right when comparing two arrays of strings with same data but in different order. May be could be useful for someone to know.

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov - can you give an example case where sorting of string arrays doesn't work?  I just tried a simple case and it seems OK; updated the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVkoa4).

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov - Fixed bug with different length arrays.

Comment: there is some JSON [here](http://justpaste.it/o7y6). When the strings were orded differently then the test didn't pass

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov - Still seems OK?  I updated the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVkoa4) with the test case, look for `GetBadJson1()` and `GetBadJson2()`.

Comment: @AndreyKomissarov It is still possible to add a bounty for a question after the answer has been accepted-- you just need to wait 48 hours after the question was originally asked.  After that, there should be a "Start a bounty" link underneath the comments section of the question.  See [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) in the Help Center.

Comment: @dbc I'm really sorry about the 'string arrays in different order'. It's was my falt it my code, which i didn't notice. Yor code seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

This could, actually, be done with less code. Not as nice, because using ***string comparison*** instead of `JValue` comparison.

Following is not an exact answer to my own question, but the goal is achieved.

```
    public static JToken Normalize(this JToken token)
    {
        var result = token;

        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                var jObject = (JObject)token;

                if (jObject != null && jObject.HasValues)
                {
                    var newObject = new JObject();

                    foreach (var property in jObject.Properties().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
                    {
                        var value = property.Value as JToken;
                        if (value != null)
                        {
                            value = Normalize(value);
                        }

                        newObject.Add(property.Name, value);
                    }
                    return newObject;
                }

                break;

            case JTokenType.Array:

                var jArray = (JArray)token;

                if (jArray != null && jArray.Count > 0)
                {
                    var normalizedArrayItems = jArray
                        .Select(x => Normalize(x))
                        .OrderBy(x => x.ToString(), StringComparer.Ordinal);

                    result = new JArray(normalizedArrayItems);
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```