# JToken to JObject Conversion or Workaround?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, json.net, type-conversion

So, I'm fairly new to C# and I'm having some trouble with the JSON.net library. Right now I'm basically trying to do a deep check against two JSON files to see whether or not they have all the same properties. I'm wanting to do it recursively and the first level is fine, but when I get to the second, I encounter the issue. Forgive if this is total garbage, but this is what I have so far. (I eagerly welcome all constructive edits) As part of my class `JsonParser` :

```
    public static void checkProps(List<JObject> jObjList)
    {

        foreach (var keyValue in jObjList[0])
        {

            var key = keyValue.Key;
            if (jObjList[1].Property(key) == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key '" + key + "' does not exist");
            }
            else if (keyValue.Value.GetType() == typeof(JObject))
            {
                List<JObject> objectsList = new List<JObject>();

                objectsList.Add(keyValue.Value);//the issue here is the error 'cannot convert from ...JToken to ...JObject'

                Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Value.GetType() + " ====>>");//but this prints 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'

                Console.WriteLine(keyValue.Value);//prints the nested object

                //here I'd like to call something like 'JsonParser.checkProps(objectsList);'

            }


        }


    }
```

So basically my (main) issue is that I'm not able to add the nested objects to my new list of JObjects because, in spite of their type writing to the console as `JObject`, the compiler (or something) only qualifies them as type `JToken`. Does anyone know how to get around this/recognize what I'm doing wrong? I obviously am missing something here. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you considered using [`JToken.DeepEquals()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepEquals.htm)?  See [Comparing JSON with JToken.DeepEquals](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeepEquals.htm).

Comment: Or if that doesn't meet your needs, you could take a look at [Compare two arbitrary JToken-s of the same structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022993).

Comment: @dbc Wow. I feel silly. `JToken.DeepEquals()` works perfectly.  Thanks so much. I was thinking that it wouldn't work if the properties were differently ordered between the objects, but you know what they say about assuming... *facepalm*.

Comment: @dbc, took a look at your linked solution and it's pretty overwhelming, tbh. I feel like if I were more of a C# vet, I might be able to get more out of it, but if there's any chance you (or anyone) could distill/pare that down a little just for this question, I'd appreciate it. Because I do still need a way to actually implement the functionality I was going for originally since I need to know what the specific diffs are between Object/Tokens. Thx!

Comment: `JObject` is a subclass of [`JTOken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).  `JToken` is the root for a JSON parse node.  Subclasses include `JObject`, `JArray`, `JValue`, `JProperty`, and a couple of obscure ones: `JRaw` and `JConstructor`.  Other that that, does `DeepEquals()` meet your needs, or do you still have a question?  If so, can you edit/update your question to say what you still need to do?