# How to sort C# Jobject

Tags: c#, sorting, asp.net-core-1.0

In my model I have `public JObject GenericData { get; set; }` for this property I need to create Jobject in my Controller that will pass data to this property. I have done this but now I need to sort data inside Jobject and I don't know how to do it. There is no sort function for Jobject out of box. 
My code in controller looks like this.

```
var attributes = _context.AttributeRecords.Include(a => a.Attribute);
    var queryRecords = attributes.Select(l => new
        {
            RecordId = l.RecordId,
            ProjectId = l.ProjectId,
            Attribute = l.Attribute.Description,
            Value = l.Value,
            InfoId = l.InfoId
        }).ToList();
        var recordsValues = queryRecords.Where(b => b.InfoId == i.InfoId).ToList();
        var jObjectValues = new JObject();
        foreach (var n in recordsValues)
        {
            if (n.Value.Contains(","))
            {
                var stringToSplit = n.Value;
                var stringValues = stringToSplit.Split(',');
                List<string> arr = new List<string>();
                var allValues = "";
                foreach (var d in stringValues)
                {
                    var values = await _context.AttributeValues.FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Key == n.Value);
                    arr.Add(values != null ? values.Description : d);
                    allValues = string.Join(",", arr);
                }
                jObjectValues.Add(n.Attribute, allValues);
            }
            else
            {
                var values = await _context.AttributeValues.FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Key == n.Value);
                jObjectValues.Add(n.Attribute, values != null ? values.Description : n.Value);
            }
            i.GenericData = jObjectValues;
        }
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Compare two arbitrary JToken-s of the same structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022993/compare-two-arbitrary-jtoken-s-of-the-same-structure).  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: No definitely not... But the answer with '.OrderBy(o => o.Attribute)' solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort Jobject you can do it like this:

```
var queryRecords = attributes.Select(l => new
    {
        RecordId = l.RecordId,
        ProjectId = l.ProjectId,
        Attribute = l.Attribute.Description,
        Value = l.Value,
        InfoId = l.InfoId
    }).OrderBy(o => o.Attribute).ToList();
```

I hope this will help you.